# Assign values to array during loop - Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, indexing

I am currently learning Python (I have a strong background in Matlab). I would like to write a loop in Python, where the size of the array increases with every iteration (i.e., I can assign a newly calculated value to a different index of a variable). For the sake of this question, I am using a very simple loop to generate the vector `t = [1 2 3 4 5]`. In Matlab, programming my desired loop would look something like this:

```
t = [];
for i = 1:5
    t(i,1) = i;
end
```

I have managed to achieve the same thing in Python with the following code:

```
result_t = []
for i in range(1,5):
    t = i
    result_t.append(t)
```

Is there a more efficient way to assign values to an array as we iterate in Python? Why is it not possible to do `t[i,1] = i` (error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple) or `t.append(t) = t` (error: '`int`' object has no attribute 'append')?

Finally, I have used the example above for simplicity. I am aware that if I wanted to generate the `vector [1 2 3 4 5]` in Python, that I could use the function "`np.arange(1,5,1)`"

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

-> My real intention isn't to produce the vector [1 2 3 4 5], but rather to assign calculated values to the index of the vector variable. For example:

```
result_b = []
b = 2
for i in range(1,5):
    t = i + b*t
    result_b.append(t)
```

Why can I not directly write `t.append(t)` or use indexing (i.e., `t[i] =  i + b*t`)?

Comment: You can use range as it already returns list in python 2. Xrange and in python3 it returns an iterable which still should fit your needs

Answer (score 20):

Appending elements while looping using `append()` is correct and it's a built-in method within `Python lists`.

However you can have the same result:

**Using list comprehension:**

```
result_t = [k for k in range(1,6)]
print(result_t)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**Using `+` operator:**

```
result_t = []
for k in range(1,6):
    result_t += [k]

print(result_t)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**Using special method `__iadd__`:**

```
result_t = []
for k in range(1,6):
    result_t.__iadd__([k])

print(result_t)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `range` function returns an iterator in modern Python.  The `list` function converts an iterator to a list.  So the following will fill your list with the values 1 to 5:

```py
result_t = list(range(1,6))  # yields [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note that in order to include `5` in the list, the range argument has to be `6`.

Your last example doesn't parse unless you assign `t` a value before the loop.  Assuming you do that, what you're doing in that case is modifying `t` each time through the loop, not just producing a linear range.  You can get this effect using the `map` function:

```py
t = 0
b = 2
def f(i):
  global t
  t = i + b*t
  return t

result_b = list(map(f, range(1, 5)))  # Yields [1, 4, 11, 26]
```

The `map` function applies the `f` function to each element of the range and returns an iterator, which is converted into a list using the `list` function. Of course, this version is more verbose than the loop, for this small example, but the technique itself is useful.

Answer (score 1):

### You can try this

```
data = ['Order-'+str(i) for i in range(1,6)]
print(data)
>>> ['Order-1', 'Order-2', 'Order-3', 'Order-4', 'Order-5']
```

Answer (score 0):

a better example from UI Testing using selenium.

```
print('Assert Pagination buttons displayed?')
all_spans = self.web_driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')

# Identify the button texts
pagination_buttons = ["Previous Page", "Next Page", "First Page"]

# Filter from all spans, only the required ones.
filtered_spans = [s for s in all_spans if s.text in pagination_buttons]

# From the filtered spans, assert all for is_displayed()
for a_span in filtered_spans:
    assert a_span.is_displayed()
    
print('Asserted Pagination buttons displayed.')
```